# Condition for second order Lagrangian to produce second order equation of motion

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

Related to  a research project I am currently doing I am studying Einstein-type Lagrangians, i.e. field Lagrangians which are second order, but whose Euler-Lagrange equations are also second order differential equations.

Consider a generic field $\phi ^i$ of unspecified type in local coordinates where $i=1,...,m$ is an index that labels the field components, and the "spacetime" coordinates are indexed with $\mu,\nu$ greek indices.

The action is of the form $$ S=\int L(\phi,d\phi,d^2\phi,x)\ \mathrm d^nx, $$ and the Euler-Lagrange equations are $$ E_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi^i}-\mathrm d_\mu\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi^i_\mu}+\mathrm d_\mu\mathrm d_\nu\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi^i_{\mu\nu}}, $$ where $\phi^i_\mu$ and $\phi^i_{\mu\nu}$ are condensed notation for the field's first and second derivatives, which shall be referred to as *velocities* and *accelerations* respectively, in analogy with classical mechanics.

Expanding the term with the two total derivatives we get the condition that $L$ must be affine in the second derivatives, i.e. is of the form $$ L(\phi,d\phi,d^2\phi,x)=A^{\mu\nu}_i(\phi,d\phi,x)\phi^i_{\mu\nu}+B(\phi,d\phi,x), $$ with $A^{\mu\nu}_i$ being symmetric in the greek index pair.

Further plugging this expression into the Euler-Lagrange equations, there are two expressions that contain third order derivatives which can be combined into the expression $$ \left(\frac{\partial A_{i}^{\nu\mu}}{\partial\phi_{,\kappa}^{j}}-\frac{\partial A_{j}^{\nu\kappa}}{\partial\phi_{,\mu}^{i}}\right)\phi_{,\kappa\mu\nu}^{j}, $$ which must identically vanish if we want the EL equations to involve no higher than second order derivatives. If I use that $\phi^i_{\mu\nu\kappa}$ is symmetric in the greek indices but otherwise these variables are freely specifiable, I get the conditions $$ 0=\frac{\partial A_{i}^{\mu\nu}}{\partial\phi_{,\kappa}^{j}}-\frac{\partial A_{j}^{\mu\nu}}{\partial\phi_{,\kappa}^{i}}+\frac{\partial A_{i}^{\nu\kappa}}{\partial\phi_{,\mu}^{j}}-\frac{\partial A_{j}^{\nu\kappa}}{\partial\phi_{,\mu}^{i}}+\frac{\partial A_{i}^{\kappa\mu}}{\partial\phi_{,\nu}^{j}}-\frac{\partial A_{j}^{\kappa\mu}}{\partial\phi_{,\nu}^{i}}.\quad(\ast) $$This is however complicated and I am not sure if it is possible to be simplified more. "Good" cases would be if this relation would be identically satisfied or if it would imply that $A^{\mu\nu}_i$ must not depend on the velocities $\phi^i_\mu$. Sadly I do not think this is the case, and I certainly cannot show it.

It would also be nice if I could express this a bit nicer, like as an exterior derivative on the jet bundle or something like that, but alas currently this is the only condition I have.

---

A bit different approach would be to still suppose that the Lagrangian is affine in $\phi^i_{\mu\nu}$, i.e. $$ L=A^{\mu\nu}_i(\phi,d\phi,x)\phi^i_{\mu\nu}+B(\phi,d\phi,x), $$ and then integrate by parts to get a first-order Lagrangian. The "naive" condition for that is that $$ A^{\mu\nu}_i(\phi,d\phi,x)=A^{\mu\nu}_i(\phi,x), $$ i.e. if the $A^{\mu\nu}_i$ does not depend on the velocities, since then a single integration by parts can make the Lagrangian first order.

The problem is that

1. I am not convinced that every second order Lagrangian with second order EoMs has a first order equivalent Lagrangian, so being able to integrate out the second derivatives might not include the most general case;
2. If we assume that $A^{\mu\nu}_i$ is *polynomial* in the velocities (which I suppose for a generally covariant Lagrangian is kinda a must), then by making lots of integration by parts maybe we can integrate out the second derivatives completely. But this gets untractable rather fast, and therefore I cannot really verify it right now, I got lost in the algebra rather fast.

---

With the above mentioned in mind, I am looking for *the condition* that a second order Lagrangian produces second order EoMs, in hopefully the simplest possible form, i.e. simpler that Eq. $(\ast)$.

Note that I specifically want this for *field* Lagrangians, for ordinary differential systems/classical mechanics, Eq. $(\ast)$ reduces to $$ 0=\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial \dot\phi^j}-\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial\dot\phi^i}, $$ which by Poincaré's lemma it implies that at least locally $$A_i(\phi,\dot\phi,x)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot \phi^i}(\phi,\dot\phi,x),$$ and this condition is rather easy to handle. The index structure of the general expression Eq. $(\ast)$ however makes it difficult to see if that equation could be locally integrated into something like this.